# How to convert JSON request body to Avro schema based Java Class?

Tags: java, json, avro, openapi

I have a Kotlin Gradle Spring Boot and Spring Webflux application which accepts a JSON as its request body. I have an `openapi` generated Java class, which the JSON request body can be casted into.

On the other hand, I also have an Avro schema which is the same as the `openapi`, except the field names have been cleaned up. The JSON request body has fields where the names start with special character, e.g. `$device_version`, `+ip_address`, `~country`. So, in the Avro schema, I remove them as Avro only allows the field name to start with either an alphabet or underscore.

Casting from JSON request body to `openapi` generated Java class is no problem, however, casting it to Avro schema generated Java class is a problem due to the field names.

I mean, I can manually set the fields but the JSON object is quite huge.

Is there an elegant and quick solution to convert that JSON request body containing different field names due to special character to the Avro schema generated class?

### Packages used

- `org.hidetake.swagger.generator`
- `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli` (with swaggerCodeGen)
- `com.commercehub.gradle.plugin:gradle-avro-plugin`

Comment: Avro can be transferred over HTTP as well, by the way. Otherwise, you can try to use the Avro Jackson libraries

Comment: Are you talking about this library https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary? And do you know if the library is able to handle the special characters?

Comment: What kind of special characters? Avro records have the same limitations as Java classes

Comment: e.g. `$device_version`, `+ip_address`, `~country`. i ended up casting the json payload to openapi generated java class and then transform that to the avro generated class, manually, without using any mapping library. i wish there was a quick solution to this.

Comment: Java doesn't allow plus or minus on fields, so I'm not sure how you got those

Comment: so the `openapi-generator-cli` takes an openapi.yml in which you can declare the actual JSON variable names, e.g. `$device_version`, `+ip_address` and `~country`, and the generated Java class will contain the "clean" names, i.e. `$deviceVersion`, `plusDeviceVersion` and `tildeCountry`, respectively. I then manually generate the Avro generated class by assigning each field from the Java class fields.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm not really sure where the problem is. Are you able to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I was actually wondering if there was an alternative to assigning the Avro generated class' fields one by one. I mentioned in my question `I mean, I can manually set the fields but the JSON object is quite huge.` So there's actually not a problem, it's just whether there's an "automated" solution, just like casting from JSON request to openapi generated Java class.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter Or have you used Jackson to convert between JSON and Avro objects? If not, then how are you currently making Java objects? You need to call a constructor and setters at somepoint...